# Why were the results of the alpha particle scattering experiment independent of the charge on the nucleus?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics

The question is as follows:
Rutherford wrote, “The main deductions from the theory are independent of whether
the central charge is positive or negative.”
Discuss why the observations did not allow Rutherford to conclude whether the
central charge is positive or negative.
You may wish to use diagrams to illustrate your response.

The mark scheme says:
[image]

What perplexes me is how would an alpha particle, labeled as 'iii' in the mark scheme, revolves around a nucleus almost all the way around and no longer undergoes circular motion after a 180-degree revolution.

Doesn't that mean the alpha particle experiences a centripetal force towards the gold nucleus for only half the revolution- the 180-degree turn? How would this be the case if there would always be an attractive force between a 'negatively' charged nucleus and the positively charged alpha particle- so that should mean the alpha particle continually revolves around the gold nucleus- as an electron would around a positive nucleus- shouldn't it?

Moreover, what if the alpha particle were heading straight toward the nucleus, as the alpha particle in 'vi' does toward the positive nucleus? Would the alpha particle come straight back because it would have been experiencing an attractive force toward the nucleus throughout so that it accelerated to high speeds and would rebound upon the collision with the negative nucleus due to the enormous kinetic energy the alpha particle would have?

Comment: As an example of an attractive central force, consider comets interacting with the sun... The math is the same whether attractive or repulsive, the only difference is whether the particle goes left vs right...

Comment: These diagrams are highly schematic, and classical. As @Jon Custer points out, in celestial mechanics, a deformed version of iii occurs all the time: think of man-made probes. You are invited to deform the diagrams provided to make them consistent with real trajectories of classical central forces, but there is hardly a point, since quantum mechanics modifies classical trajectories anyway. Just focus on the rough  features of the intuitive paradigm. There is an elegant explanation in QM, but not touched upon here.

Comment: @CosmasZachos - Rutherford scattering is a completely classical situation, no QM required. Rutherford got the math right in 1911 before QM. Since the paper was "The Scattering of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ Particles by Matter and the Structure of the Atom" he was already considering various combinations of (+) and (-) particles.

Comment: @Jon Custer, of course; R's cross section is reviewed in all mechanics texts, e.g. Goldstein's; I was hinting to the OP that there is a richer/deeper story waiting in the wings, *when* QM is introduced....

Comment: alright. I guess I'll have to delve deeper into this matter to figure it out.
what about everything I mentioned in the final paragraph though? What are the odds of that happening?